# Would like to see this: Hardware -> Available Drivers

Tags: drivers, hardware

Notes on this site suggest that I can see a list of all hardware + avaliable drivers in software manager under additional drivers.  I only see broadcom wifi+ some drivers.
Where are the other drivers, such as display?.
I have a dell Inspiron 9400, 32 bit.  I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and ugraded to 18.04.  I have a ati mobility radeon x1400 and I am interested in testing drivers other than the default.  I also have a usb 1200 dual band A/C adapter.  I want to add a driver to that as well.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

My Aloha, in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The `lshw` command (run from a command prompt) will do what you appear to want.

```
sudo lshw > lshw.log
nano lshw.log
```

It lists all hardware, and the associated drivers.